# Postgresql json-generation from dynamic SQL

Tags: json, postgresql

Is there any way of using the json-functions, such as json_agg when you're using dynamic SQL?

The documentation leads to think that ref cursors should be used when returning multiple rows. But then iterating over ref cursors appear to involve fetch/loop etc or is there a way of doing some sort of json_agg from (select * from my_ref_cursor)?

Of course there is the option of ref cursor + loop + concating json rows one at a time but that doesn't sound very effective.

Thanks in advance,
  Nik

Comment: It should be possible, but without seeing your code that uses dynamic SQL this is impossible to answer. Why can't you integrate those json functions into your dynamic SQL?

Comment: Hmm, you can do that? I'll give it a try, I was stuck with the idea that the generation of the input the the json should be dynamic but why not the whole query?

Comment: `execute format('select to_jsonb(t) from %I as t', some_variable)`

Comment: `do $$
declare
 s text := 'select json_agg(c) from (select * from company) c ';
 j json;
begin
 execute s into j;
 raise notice '%', j;
end;
$$`

Could do the job, the rest is just string manipulation. Thanks for the pointer